# How to log a "route not found"

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, listener

I found on internet that in laravel 4 it is possible to include this code to log the `NotFoundHttpException` error.

```
/*
 * Error listeners
 */
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code) {
    if ($exception instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException)
        Log::error('NotFoundHttpException Route: ' . Request::url() );

    Log::error($exception);
});
```

I'm using Laravel 5 and I didn't find the `start/global.php` file in which insert the code above. In Laravel. 5 it is not present anymore the `start/global.php` file, so my question is: where I should copy this code to log the `NotFoundHttpException Route` error?
I would use this code because by launching the command `php artisan route:list` I receive an NotFoundHttpException that I'm not able to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the file `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` there's a method called `report()` which has the exception provided as an argument. Check if the exception is an instance of the `NotFoundHttpException` and you're good to go.

```
public function report(Throwable $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
        // Do something here.
    }

    parent::report($exception);
}
```

Comment: I found the file Handler.php but I think it registers error when I navigate in the app.. If I lauche the command php artisan route:list it not writes error on Log. Am I correct?

Comment: Oh sorry. I think I totally misunderstood you. You can use the `--verbose` flag with the `route:list` command to get the full error stack: `php artisan -v route:list`. Maybe that'll help you?

Comment: Yes, it helped!